# List of values in property files for Spring Boot, configured with square brackets syntax

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Lets say I have a properties file `application.properties` with the following content:

```
items[0]=whatever0
items[1]=whatever1
items[2]=whatever2
```

And I want to use this with @Value:

```java
// this is not working
@Value("${items}")
List<String> items;
```

Is it somehow possible to make this work with `@Value`?
Please be aware that I do NOT want to use `items=whatever0,whatever1,whatever2`.
This "square bracket" syntax is working with `@ConfigurationProperties`, but I do not know how to make it also work with `@Value`. TYVM.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can do this.

First way::

```
public class TypeConfiguration(){
    @Value(#{'${types}'.split(',')})
    private List<String> types;
}
```

Configuration file::
types: type1,type2,type3

Second Way::

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="types")
 public class TypeConfiguration(){
  Map<String, String> typeMap;
  // setter, getter
}
```

ConfigurationFile::
types:
typeMap:
type1: TYPE1
type2: TYPE2

Or you can also create your own custom object having all the field names and use them here.